# Laravel dispatch queue always intermediately run

Tags: laravel, queue, dispatch

I am trying to dispatch jobs in Laravel into mysql. If I do

> dispatch(new SendBroadcastSMS());

or

> SendBroadcastSMS::dispatch()->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));

The job always runs intermediately. In my job, I set to sleep 30 seconds and my current controller/page that calls dispatch also waiting for 30 seconds and echo the job return. Why? It should run in the background via worker right? Or I misunderstand with the laravel queue?

My job is like below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendBroadcastSMS implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(30);
        echo "test";
//       dd($this->sendSms("6281517777767","test message"));
        //
    }
}
```

my queue driver is database mysql and I also not receieved any row in `job` table

> QUEUE_DRIVER=database

Comment: What's your queue driver?

Comment: @Mozammil database mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUEUE_DRIVER` is not the property you should set in your `.env` file.
The correct property is [`QUEUE_CONNECTION`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/queue.php#L16).

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Comment: It was `QUEUE_DRIVER` till [5.6](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.6/config/queue.php#L16)

Comment: I didn't know you were using Laravel 5.6 :)

Comment: Hi, yes I use 5.7 and didnt know if config was changed. but I changed to QUEUE_CONNECTION=database , still have same problem persist, I already clear config cache still happened, why?

Comment: after I restarted my laptop it work perfectly, thank you